# Failing to start grakn

Tags: vaticle-typedb

I'm trying to start grakn but it fails :

```
grakn server start 
====================================================================================================
      ________  _____     _______  __    __  __    __      _______  _______  _____     _______
     |   __   ||   _  \  |   _   ||  |  /  /|  \  |  |    |   _   ||   _   ||   _  \  |   ____|
     |  |  |__||  | |  | |  | |  ||  | /  / |   \ |  |    |  | |__||  | |  ||  | |  | |  |
     |  | ____ |  |_| /  |  |_|  ||  |/  /  |    \|  |    |  |     |  | |  ||  |_| /  |  |____
     |  ||_   ||   _  \  |   _   ||   _  \  |   _    |    |  |  __ |  | |  ||   _  \  |   ____|
     |  |__|  ||  | \  \ |  | |  ||  | \  \ |  | \   |    |  |_|  ||  |_|  ||  | \  \ |  |____
     |________||__|  \__\|__| |__||__|  \__\|__|  \__|    |_______||_______||__|  \__\|_______|

                                         THE KNOWLEDGE GRAPH
====================================================================================================
                                                                                      Version:  1.8.3
Starting Storage....FAILED!
Unable to start Storage.
Process exited with code '1': 'Unrecognized VM option 'CrashOnOutOfMemoryError'
Did you mean 'OnOutOfMemoryError=<value>'?
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
'
An error has occurred during boot-up. Please run 'grakn server status' or check the logs located under the 'logs' directory.
Process exited with code '1': 'Unrecognized VM option 'CrashOnOutOfMemoryError'
Did you mean 'OnOutOfMemoryError=<value>'?
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
'
```

Comment: What java version do you have installed? Open a new console and type `java -version`.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of this error is that you have an incompatible Java version installed.

You can check the Java version by running `java -version` in a terminal window.

Grakn 1.8 requires at least version `1.8.0_92` of Java to run.

See also https://github.com/graknlabs/grakn/issues/5267 for more discussion on this topic.

Comment: I use Java  version "1.8.0_77"

Comment: Ok so this is indeed the issue. Your Java version must be at least 1.8.0_92. Install an up-to-date version of Java 8.